# How to click on next button in Linkedin with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a problem to find element "Next Button" and click that with Selenium in Python within the [webpage](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=ie%3B%5C)

Code trials:

```
try: 
   driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".artdeco-pagination__button--next").click()
except NoSuchElementException: 
   print("No Next button, skipped.")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>Next</kbd> element on the [webpage](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=ie%3B%5C) is a dynamic element, so to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=ie%3B%5C")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Next'] li-icon.artdeco-button__icon +span.artdeco-button__text))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/companies/?origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=ie%3B%5C")   
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='artdeco-button__text' and text()='Next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```